# How to access data of previous rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access the previous (or further back) row to use as a value in a new column. Have tried several approaches with enumerate, iterrows and iloc but end up with the same problem, they use the last value. The following code is used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':(50.033,50.025,49.979,49.954,49.936,49.935,49.93)})

df['a']=df.diff()

def my_func_disch(x):
    if abs(x) >= 0 and abs(x) <= 0.009:
        for index,row in df.iterrows():
            eff_disch = row['values']  
    else:
        eff_disch = 'xxx'
    return eff_disch

df["b"] = df.a.apply(my_func_disch)
```

Which produces:

```
   values      a      b
0  50.033    NaN    xxx
1  50.025 -0.008  49.93
2  49.979 -0.046    xxx
3  49.954 -0.025    xxx
4  49.936 -0.019    xxx
5  49.935  0.000  49.93
6  49.930 -0.005  49.93
```

And I would like it to produce:

```
   values      a      b
0  50.033    NaN    xxx
1  50.025 -0.008  50.033
2  49.979 -0.046    xxx
3  49.954 -0.025    xxx
4  49.936 -0.019    xxx
5  49.935  0.000  49.936
6  49.930 -0.005  49.935
```

Comment: look at [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `apply`,  but instead use vectorized [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which is faster and more readable:

```
df['b'] = np.where(df['a'].abs().between(0, 0.009, inclusive=True), df['values'].shift(), 'xxx')
#   values      a                  b
#0  50.033    NaN                xxx
#1  50.025 -0.008             50.033
#2  49.979 -0.046                xxx
#3  49.954 -0.025                xxx
#4  49.936 -0.019                xxx
#5  49.935  0.000  49.93600000000001
#6  49.930 -0.005             49.935
```

The first argument specifies when to do something (when the [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) is [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) some values), the second and third specify what to return when it is `True` or `False` respectively. You want the values-column [`shifted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Your solution doesn't work because you always iterate over the entire DataFrame (which is almost never the way to go) only stopping after iterating over the last row, therefore returning the last value.

Comment: Perfect and quick answer. However for further calculations I would still like to do calculations specific values in column ['a'], is there a proper way to do this?